# What is not selected

Tags: mysql, join

I run a left join on two tables. How do I display what was not selected in the query? I have looked around for a while but not know what I am looking for has me stuck.

```
SELECT * FROM company 
LEFT JOIN users ON company.USERID = users.ID 
WHERE NOT USR_STATUS = 'ACTIVE' 
AND role = '' 
ORDER BY users.USR_FIRSTNAME
```

Comment: See [this great explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Why the down vote @juergen so I won't do it again.

Comment: I did not downvote. But your question is way too vague to help you and you put no effort in it. Add example data, table structure, expected output and the query you tried to your question.

Comment: @juergen sorry for finger pointing but thank you for the advise.

Comment: *How do I display what was not selected in the query* What does that mean?

Comment: Ok @juergen so when I do the left join in the edit above. I want the itmes that were not selected from the user table. Based on the were condition.

Comment: Look at those questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738198/summing-the-sum-of-two-tables and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24738330/sql-id-column-with-underscore-or-period. This is how a question should be. An example of data makes it way more clear than just text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users LEFT OUTER JOIN pmt_company ON pmt_company.USERID = users.USR_UID
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you give me the statement?

It seems to me that you should reverse you're were statement as in:

```
where number = 1
```

make it

```
where number <> 1
```

@EDIT 08:13 15-07-2014

You can try to make an subquery similar to this?

```
SELECT * FROM company 
LEFT JOIN users ON company.USERID = users.ID 
WHERE USR_STATUS NOT IN ( SELECT USR_STATUS from users where USR_STATUS = 'ACTIVE')
AND role = null
ORDER BY users.USR_FIRSTNAME
```

This might not be the good query. But with a subquery it returns a list and searches which value is in or not in this list. so you can use IN or NOT IN. For a definitive answer, I would need the structure of your tables and need to know what you want to select.

Answer (score 0):

You must negate where statement. par example query

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE condition
```

change to

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE not (condition)
```