# Summing the SUM of two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've two tables:

```
SELECT a."StartTime", a."DiameterTotal"[1]
FROM sdp1a_cip a
WHERE date_trunc('minute', a."StartTime") = TIMESTAMP '2014-07-12 23:51:00'

"2014-07-12 23:51:00";4224
"2014-07-12 23:51:10";4251
"2014-07-12 23:51:20";4207
"2014-07-12 23:51:31";4204
"2014-07-12 23:51:41";4233
"2014-07-12 23:51:51";4174
```

and

```
SELECT b."StartTime", b."DiameterTotal"[1]
FROM sdp1b_cip b
WHERE date_trunc('minute', b."StartTime") = TIMESTAMP '2014-07-12 23:51:00'

"2014-07-12 23:51:02";4235
"2014-07-12 23:51:12";4100
"2014-07-12 23:51:22";4266
"2014-07-12 23:51:32";4292
"2014-07-12 23:51:42";4199
"2014-07-12 23:51:52";4109
```

I want an output like this:

```
"2014-07-12 23:51:0";50494
```

which is the sum of the SUM(DiameterTotal[1]) of each table grouped by the date_trunc('minute',..) of the time stamp.

now, I've tried multiple combinations (no sql expert here) but all are giving me the sum of 36 rows (cartesian product of the rows of the two tables).

one of the queries I've tried is:

```
SELECT date_trunc('minute',sdp1a_cip."StartTime"), SUM(sdp1a_cip."DiameterTotal"[1]) + SUM(sdp1b_cip."DiameterTotal"[1])
FROM sdp1a_cip, sdp1b_cip
WHERE date_trunc('minute', sdp1a_cip."StartTime") = TIMESTAMP '2014-07-12 23:51:00'
AND date_trunc('minute',sdp1a_cip."StartTime") = date_trunc('minute',sdp1b_cip."StartTime")
group by date_trunc('minute',sdp1a_cip."StartTime")
```

**EDIT**

this query worked but it's taking too long:

```
SELECT "StartTime", SUM(recCount) FROM (
  SELECT date_trunc('minute', a."StartTime") as "StartTime", SUM(a."DiameterTotal"[1]) as recCount
  FROM sdp1a_cip a
  WHERE date_trunc('minute', a."StartTime") = TIMESTAMP '2014-07-12 23:51:00'
  Group By date_trunc('minute', a."StartTime")

  UNION ALL

  SELECT date_trunc('minute', b."StartTime") as "StartTime", SUM(b."DiameterTotal"[1]) as recCount
  FROM sdp1b_cip b
  WHERE date_trunc('minute', b."StartTime") = TIMESTAMP '2014-07-12 23:51:00'
  Group By date_trunc('minute', b."StartTime")
) g
Group By g."StartTime"
```

Comment: You can `UNION ALL` the `sdp1a_cip` and `sdp1b_cip` tables (with proper filters) and `GROUP BY` the union.

Comment: doesn't that assume that the number of rows on the two is equal ? (remember, no sql expert)

Comment: You can `UNION` or `UNION ALL` tables with any number of rows. The only constraint - both "query parts" (actual tables or sub-queries) must have same number of columns and column types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `UNION ALL`?

```
SELECT "StartTime", SUM(recCount) FROM (
  SELECT date_trunc('minute', a."StartTime") as "StartTime", SUM(a."DiameterTotal"[1]) as recCount
  FROM sdp1a_cip a
  WHERE date_trunc('minute', a."StartTime") = TIMESTAMP '2014-07-12 23:51:00'
  Group By date_trunc('minute', a."StartTime")

  UNION ALL

  SELECT date_trunc('minute', b."StartTime") as "StartTime", SUM(b."DiameterTotal"[1]) as recCount
  FROM sdp1b_cip b
  WHERE date_trunc('minute', b."StartTime") = TIMESTAMP '2014-07-12 23:51:00'
  Group By date_trunc('minute', b."StartTime")
) g
Group By g."StartTime"
```

I haven't tested this.

Comment: It is not `count(*)`. It is `SUM("DiameterTotal")`

Comment: This query wont group the records by minutes. You need `group by date_trunc('minute',"StartTime")`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto It is `SUM("DiameterTotal"[1])` to be precise.

Comment: This query still wont work. You can not select `b."StartTime"` when you group by `date_trunc('minute',sdp1b_cip."StartTime")`. Also you can not refferenct table `sdp1b_cip` if you have given it an alias `b`

Comment: this worked for me but it is taking a very long time, aroung 32 seconds (when I run the two subqueries alone, they both take around 2 seconds only !). isn't there another way to do it ?

Comment: not the exact same, I've edited my question to include the version that worked

Comment: my bad, it doesn't take that long, I don't know what happened the first time, I'm closing the subject, thanks all for your help